# How do I make my program abort (without any lib)

Tags: c

I have an exercise in class where I have to copy the `strstr()` function in C (from `<string.h>` library). Here is my code

```
char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}
```

This code is fully functional but when I try with a `dest` string that is smaller than the `src` string, it shows an unpredictable result that ends up overwriting `src` too. The original `strstr()` function's answer to that is to abort program in that situation. How can I make my program abort given that I can't use the `abort()` function?

Comment: `strstr()`? or`strcpy()`?

Comment: Read about undefined  behavior. Stricto sensu, the answer is implementation specific. You might have a standard conforming C implementation which never aborts, but instead explode your computer, or terminate the universe.

Comment: `How can I make my program abort`... if you're in luck, UB will do it for you. :-)

Comment: IMHO, you can _prevent_ UB, but cannot _handle_ UB, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: BTW, your code won't work if dest and src overlap.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, a don't think the original `strcpy()` does it either.

Comment: Not related to the question, but it's good practice to use `const` for stuff that the function won't change, as a way of documenting your code; in this case `src`: `char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`.

Comment: Use `strncpy`? Pretty sure `strcpy` is deprecated.

Comment: Actually this is a special school, I'm just doing my entry exam and we have to code our own library functions, today's exercices set are about string manipulation, we have to copy strcpy, strncpy, strstr, strcmp, strncmp, strupcase, strlowcase, strcapitalize, str_is_alpha, str_is_numeric, str_is_lowercase, str_is_uppercase, str_is_printable, strcat, strncat, strlcat, strlcpy, putnbr_base, atoi_base, putstr_non_printable, print_memory. We can't use any lib, only write() from <unistd>. This is my 5th day of C, sorry if I seem irrelevant.

Comment: @wallek876 it does when I try to putstr() the result. maybe with printf it wouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

You must check your string.
May be one of them is NULL.

When you do : `While (str[i] ..)`

You don't know if (str) is NULL or not.

Do : 
`While (str && str[i] != '\0')`

It's better.

You can also check if dest is malloc fine because if you don't have any memory for your string dest you can't assign value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a compact implementation

```
char * ft_strcpy(char * dest, const char * src) {
    if (strlen(dest) < strlen(src)) { /* abort(); or exit(1); */ }
    char * s = dest;
    while (*dest++ = *src++);
    return s;
}
```

The actual bounds checking is implemented in the safer version of `strcpy`, i.e. `strcpy_s`. You can find an implementation in [Safe C Library](http://sourceforge.net/p/safeclib/code/ci/master/tree/src/safeclib/strcpy_s.c).